# Regular expression is not working properly in Swift 3

Tags: regex, swift, nsregularexpression

I am trying to parse string data in Swift, the best solution that I can think of is using a regular expression. The problem is with detecting a substring with the pattern **{{...}}** The ... represents a string of any length. I created a regular expression using an online debugger. Here is the expression and the corresponding result:

[image: the expression and the corresponding result]

But when I use same regular expression in Swift, it doesn't work. Below is the code that I am using.

```
if let match = data.range(of: "{{(.*)}}", options: .regularExpression) 
{ some code logic }
```

But it is not working. I have hardcoded in the exact same string as in the test string above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should escape the curly braces with backslashes:

```
let match = data.range(of: "\\{\\{(.*)\\}\\}", options: .regularExpression)
```